# Displaying information on minimalistic long panels

Tags: gui-design, information-architecture

I had a question about displaying information on long panels. For example, the first is an empty panel and the second is what I'm doing right now:

[image: Long Panel] [image: Long panel with information]

The main issue here is that putting text directly onto the panel makes it look ugly or rather, takes away from the user experience. The information is on various topics such as: projects, philosophy, about me etc.

**What is a way for me to display information in a way that is not cluttered?**

**Edit:** These panels are a part of my [website](http://www.jeelshah.me) design. Essentially, the front of the panel is an icon which indicates what the panel is about. When the user hovers over the panel, the panel turns around and some information is displayed. The main issue I'm having is that any attempt to add information to the panels results in ugliness or takes away from the minimal design.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Jeel.  Can you clarify your question a bit? Where will these panels be used? What particular aspect(s) of them are you concerned about?

Comment: Why would you want to show a lot of text in narrow vertical panels? From start that's a bad idea, you don't to switch between lines after reading 3-6 words, so uncomfortable. But as @3nafish said, please add more context.

Comment: I have updated the question to add more details. If information cannot be added to the panels in a good way then what are the alternatives? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making it an accordion style interface. Keep the panels but have them expand horizontally (while shrinking the width of the others others) slightly when a user hovers over. Instead of the "flip" effect.
You can add easing to the animation to make the motion feel more fluid.
This would result in more horizontal space within each panel.
I do like the layout of your site, though I found it a little jarring that things were flipping around all over the place whenever I move my mouse.

Comment: If I choose to go with the accordion style interface, how would you recommend that I display the information on the larger panel?

Comment: I would center the text within each panel vertically. The user will likely roll over the panel somewhere in the center of the screen and not towards the top so they would expect to see the results closer to their mouse event. Does that make sense? I would also maybe use larger font and consider using white as the font color, maybe with a 90% opacity, that's just my opinion :)